# Yocto: set date and time without ntp

Tags: date, yocto, ntp, hwclock

on my embedded device with YOCTO and none ethernet connection  I would set a specific date and keep it udpdate after the device power-off.
I tryed with :

```
date --set '2022-05-25 11:17:00'
hwclock --utc --systohc
poweroff
```

but at power on the dat&time are switched back to old value

The same result using :

```
timedatectl
```

where ntp is disable, RTC local in TZ is enable and system clock synchromized is enable.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you be more precise? In my opinion, your description is misleading. I understood that you have RTC on your device, but you can't update the time from NTP. Can you confirm? As I understood the time is back to the default value after the device restart?

Comment: Yes, but the problem was in dts file, the supplyer doesn't activate the RTC

Comment: "Yes, but the problem was in dts file," - Did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, we just verified, It's necessary  add : aliases {
                                                                    rtc1 = &snvs_rtc;
                                                                       };